# How to detect language code based on input text using javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, es6-modules

Here i am trying to detect language code based on text. I have found below one, but it is not working for some languages. 
**chrome.i18n.detectLanguage(string text, function callback){....}** 
I am stuck on this. Could anybody please tell me any existing javascript will solve this problem.

```
 var text = "美國國家環境保護局 - 中文 (繁體版)";
     var text1 = "logmein hamachi скачать";

     var listarray = [];
     listarray.push(text);
     listarray.push(text1);
    for(var i=0;i<listarray.length;i++){
       chrome.i18n.detectLanguage(listarray[i],function(result) {
       for(i = 0; i < result.languages.length; i++) {
          outputLang = result.languages[i].language + " ";
          console.log(outputLang);
     }
    }
```

Here for some texts, I am getting two languages with percentage of content.
var text1 = "logmein hamachi скачать"; [{"language":"de","percentage":51},{"language":"ru","percentage":48}]}

Is there any way to detect only one language as google does?

Comment: There's no such API in JavaScript. Use Google or similar search site to find an existing library that implements detection.

Comment: @wOxxOm what makes you think there isn't? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/i18n/detectLanguage

Comment: that code only work in WebExtensions @PatrickHund

Comment: I assumed the question was about extensions, because of the google-chrome-extension tag

Comment: @PatrickHund, detectLanguage doesn't work for the OP as stated in the question.

Answer (score 0):

using google API we can detect input language 
https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/detecting-language

Answer (score -1):

The code you cite in your question only works inside google chrome browser extensions. Read more https://developer.chrome.com/extensions

You can try `navigator.language` or `navigator.languages` to get the browser language but this has some issues. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorLanguage/language

One easy way to check for all user accepted language is to read the user request headers from within a server. Then return the `request.headers['accept-language']` info to your client. Read more https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Language

```js
var url = 'https://foda-app.herokuapp.com/db?get=lang';
// this server returns the request.headers['accept-language']
// read the code https://github.com/rafaelcastrocouto/foda/blob/master/server.js#L166

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
  // Process the server response here.
  if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE &&
      xhr.status === 200) {
    console.log(xhr.responseText);
  }
}
xhr.open('GET', url);
xhr.send();
```

Even better is to store the `request.headers['accept-language']` in the first HTML response to avoid the extra request.

Comment: The question was how to detect the language of a given string, not the browser's accepted languages.